# Как при помощи Joda получить 2019-08-22T13:26:36.447019Z

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jodatime

Нужно получить формат времени ввиде: 2019-08-22T13:26:36.447019Z, но как это сделать что-то не вкурю. Или при помощи стандартных библиотек JAVA. Есть в ISO - но он немного не такой: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]`, после точки вроде как пикосекунды, а по исо мили... Дак ещё и эта `Z` на конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всегда можете использовать `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date d=new Date();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'000Z'").format(d));
```

> I/System.out: 2019-08-23T14:22:23.177000Z

Возможно кто-то знает более изящное решение.

p.s. этот формат называется **ISO 8601**

Comment: Да вполне такой вариант имеет право на жизнь.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал это вот так:

```
"${DateTime.now().toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondFraction().withZoneUTC())}000Z"
```